# Click During Inter-App Audio Recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I have been attempting to recording my input during an inter-app audio session on iOS 9. The speaker output sounds fine but the recorded file has a rhythmic clicking sound.
The waveform looks like below...

[image]

I have tweaked every setting and parameter I can think of and nothing seems to work.

Here are the format settings (stream settings are identical)...

```
    AudioStreamBasicDescription fileFormat;
fileFormat.mSampleRate          = kSessionSampleRate;
fileFormat.mFormatID            = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
fileFormat.mFormatFlags         = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked;
fileFormat.mFramesPerPacket     = 1;
fileFormat.mChannelsPerFrame    = 1;
fileFormat.mBitsPerChannel      = 32;       //tone is correct but there is still pops
fileFormat.mBytesPerPacket      = sizeof(Float32);
fileFormat.mBytesPerFrame       = sizeof(Float32);
```

Here are the stream settings...

```
        //connect instrument to output
AudioComponentDescription componentDescription = unit.componentDescription;
AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &componentDescription);
OSStatus status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &_instrumentUnit);
NSLog(@"%d",status);
AudioUnitElement instrumentOutputBus = 0;
AudioUnitElement ioUnitInputElement = 0;

    //connect instrument unit to remoteIO output's input bus
AudioUnitConnection connection;
connection.sourceAudioUnit = _instrumentUnit;
connection.sourceOutputNumber = instrumentOutputBus;
connection.destInputNumber = ioUnitInputElement;
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_ioUnit,
                              kAudioUnitProperty_MakeConnection,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                              ioUnitInputElement,
                              &connection,
                              sizeof(connection));
NSLog(@"%d",status);
UInt32 maxFrames = 1024; //I tried setting this to 4096 but it did not help
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_instrumentUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                0,
                                &maxFrames,
                                sizeof(maxFrames));
NSLog(@"%d",status);



_connectedInstrument = YES;
_instrumentIconImageView.image = unit.icon;
NSLog(@"Remote Instrument connected");
status = AudioUnitInitialize(_ioUnit);
NSLog(@"%d",status);
status = AudioOutputUnitStart(_ioUnit);
NSLog(@"%d",status);
status = AudioUnitInitialize(_instrumentUnit);
NSLog(@"%d",status);
[self setupFile];
```

Here is my callback...

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void                              *inRefCon,
                                 AudioUnitRenderActionFlags         *ioActionFlags,
                                 const AudioTimeStamp               *inTimeStamp,
                                 UInt32                             inBusNumber,
                                 UInt32                             inNumberFrames,
                                 AudioBufferList                    *ioData)
{
    ViewController* This = This = (__bridge ViewController *)inRefCon;
    if (inBusNumber == 0 && !(*ioActionFlags & kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError))
    {
            ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(This->fileRef, inNumberFrames, ioData);
    }

    return noErr;
}
```

[Full view controller code here](https://gist.github.com/Pescolly/5b72bbea1470ccf001b6c74bff9d5daf)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this on a device or the simulator?

Comment: @Dave Its on an iPad Mini 2.

Comment: Figured it out. I had to check the flags AND transfer the render callback to the IO Unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are writing to file pre and post render.  In your render callback, change your if statement to only write on post render.

```
if (inBusNumber == 0 && *ioActionFlags == kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender){
    ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(This->fileRef, inNumberFrames, ioData);
}
```

ExtAudioFileWriteAsync does some internal copying and buffering so it's fine to use in the render callback as long as you prime it before the first write.

Comment: By priming do you mean doing this? ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(fileRef, 0, NULL);

Comment: @Pescolly Yep,  this sets up the internal ring buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you'll have to check for **both**:

- post-render action flags
- post render error

The critical part of your *callback* will probably have to look somewhat like this:

```
if (*ioActionFlags & kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender){
    static int TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError = (1 << 8);
    if (!(*ioActionFlags & TEMP_kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRenderError))
    { 
         ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(This->fileRef, inNumberFrames, ioData);
         //whichever additional code needed
         // { … }
    }
```